# BLE IOS : connectPeripheral results a didDisconnectPeripheral with null error SOMETIMES

Tags: ios, ios7, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I'm working on a project which use BLE of ios

It works great except that sometimes when I call `connectPeripherical` (with retrieve p or with central scan), it takes a 10 seconds and after it disconnects the peripheric (`didDisconnectPeripheral` with null error). This error appears sometimes and I have to turn off/turn on my iphone to make it work.

I'm really lost about this error.

Any idea?

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Did you disconnect your self? If so, that's normal that the error is nil.
In this delegate method, you should do: `if (error){//do something, alertview, etc.}else{NSLog(@"Disconnected");}`

Comment: No, I do not disconnect myself. It disconnects automatically after 10sec and go in didDisconnectPeripheral with nil error.  It does this only sometimes...... I do know what to do..

Answer (score 2):

I got it to work. CoreBluetooth framework is smart and does bring down the connection after single reads / writes are performed. The way you can keep the connection live is by subscribing to at least one characteristic value from the peripheral.

Here's how you can do that:
Central Code:
When you find a characteristic for a peripheral you are interested in subscribe to it like this
[yourPeripheral setNotifyValue:YES forCharacteristic:characteristic];

Works like a charm :)